# Ubuntu VM on vSphere constantly crashing

Tags: server, 18.04

I'm currently struggeling to find the reason why my ubuntu VM keeps crashing. Fresh 18.04.1 ubuntu server install which only has plex media server installed. The host is a PowerEdge T620 and vSphere reported this: **The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. Power off or reset the virtual machine.**

I've had this issue on my old plex vm and that was the reason I started a new vm to get rid of these crashes. But to no success...

These are the last few lines of the kernel.log:

```
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    5.421494] Guest personality initialized and is active
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    5.422951] VMCI host device registered (name=vmci, major=10, minor=55)
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    5.424278] Initialized host personality
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    5.498592] iscsi: registered transport (iser)
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    5.589929] NET: Registered protocol family 40
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    5.664897] Adding 4194300k swap on /swap.img.  Priority:-2 extents:6 across:4489212k SSFS
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    6.126872] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    6.277401] RAPL PMU: API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 3 fixed counters, 10737418240 ms ovfl timer
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    6.277405] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp0-core 2^-0 Joules
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    6.277407] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain package 2^-0 Joules
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    6.277409] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain dram 2^-0 Joules
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    6.372933] EDAC sbridge: Seeking for: PCI ID 8086:3ca0
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    6.372946] EDAC sbridge:  Ver: 1.1.2 
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    6.995020] EXT4-fs (sda2): recovery complete
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    6.995191] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    7.439592] audit: type=1400 audit(1537988732.074:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/lxc-start" pid=932 comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    7.442551] audit: type=1400 audit(1537988732.078:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=933 comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    7.442558] audit: type=1400 audit(1537988732.078:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=933 comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    7.442562] audit: type=1400 audit(1537988732.078:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=933 comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    7.446265] audit: type=1400 audit(1537988732.082:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=936 comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    7.449663] audit: type=1400 audit(1537988732.086:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=931 comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    7.449670] audit: type=1400 audit(1537988732.086:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=931 comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    7.449675] audit: type=1400 audit(1537988732.086:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=931 comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    7.449679] audit: type=1400 audit(1537988732.086:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=931 comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    7.451906] audit: type=1400 audit(1537988732.086:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default" pid=930 comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    7.482714] vmxnet3 0000:03:00.0 ens160: intr type 3, mode 0, 5 vectors allocated
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [    7.484048] vmxnet3 0000:03:00.0 ens160: NIC Link is Up 10000 Mbps
Sep 26 19:05:34 plex kernel: [   10.155817] new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
Sep 26 19:05:35 plex kernel: [   10.775410] FS-Cache: Loaded
Sep 26 19:05:35 plex kernel: [   10.812012] FS-Cache: Netfs 'cifs' registered for caching
Sep 26 19:05:35 plex kernel: [   10.812171] Key type cifs.spnego registered
Sep 26 19:05:35 plex kernel: [   10.812176] Key type cifs.idmap registered
Sep 26 19:05:35 plex kernel: [   10.812996] No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.
Sep 26 19:05:35 plex kernel: [   10.813010] No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.
Sep 26 19:05:35 plex kernel: [   10.813023] No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.
Sep 26 19:05:35 plex kernel: [   10.813234] No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.
Sep 26 19:05:40 plex kernel: [   15.940127] random: crng init done
Sep 26 19:05:40 plex kernel: [   15.940143] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
```

Where else should I stark looking?

This is the only vm which crashes...

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:
Syslog:

```
Sep 26 19:05:35 plex systemd[1]: Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
Sep 26 19:05:35 plex systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
Sep 26 19:05:35 plex systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
Sep 26 19:05:35 plex systemd[1]: Reached target Login Prompts.
Sep 26 19:05:35 plex snapd[1227]: 2018/09/26 19:05:35.853485 daemon.go:343: started snapd/2.34.2+18.04 (series 16; classic) ubuntu/18.04 (amd64) linux/4.15.0-34-generic.
Sep 26 19:05:35 plex systemd[1]: Started Snappy daemon.
Sep 26 19:05:35 plex systemd[1]: Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
Sep 26 19:05:35 plex systemd[1]: Started Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
Sep 26 19:05:35 plex systemd[1]: Starting Apply the settings specified in cloud-config...
Sep 26 19:05:35 plex systemd[1]: Reached target Multi-User System.
Sep 26 19:05:35 plex systemd[1]: Reached target Graphical Interface.
Sep 26 19:05:35 plex systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
Sep 26 19:05:35 plex systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
Sep 26 19:05:37 plex cloud-init[1529]: Cloud-init v. 18.3-9-g2e62cb8a-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 running 'modules:config' at Wed, 26 Sep 2018 19:05:36 +0000. Up 12.19 seconds.
Sep 26 19:05:37 plex systemd[1]: Started Apply the settings specified in cloud-config.
Sep 26 19:05:37 plex systemd[1]: Starting Execute cloud user/final scripts...
Sep 26 19:05:38 plex cloud-init[1620]: Cloud-init v. 18.3-9-g2e62cb8a-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 running 'modules:final' at Wed, 26 Sep 2018 19:05:38 +0000. Up 13.59 seconds.
Sep 26 19:05:38 plex cloud-init[1620]: Cloud-init v. 18.3-9-g2e62cb8a-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 finished at Wed, 26 Sep 2018 19:05:38 +0000. Datasource DataSourceNoCloud [seed=/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net][dsmode=net].  Up 14.04 seconds
Sep 26 19:05:38 plex systemd[1]: Started Execute cloud user/final scripts.
Sep 26 19:05:38 plex systemd[1]: Reached target Cloud-init target.
Sep 26 19:05:38 plex systemd[1]: Startup finished in 4.585s (kernel) + 9.575s (userspace) = 14.161s.
Sep 26 19:05:39 plex snapd[1227]: 2018/09/26 19:05:39.903127 handlers.go:388: Reported install problem for "core" as 2808182e-c1bf-11e8-9260-fa163ee63de6 OOPSID
Sep 26 19:05:40 plex kernel: [   15.940127] random: crng init done
Sep 26 19:05:40 plex kernel: [   15.940143] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
Sep 26 19:06:03 plex systemd-timesyncd[812]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Sep 26 19:08:45 plex systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of plex.
Sep 26 19:08:45 plex systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
Sep 26 19:08:45 plex systemd[1]: Started Session 1 of user plex.
Sep 26 19:08:46 plex systemd[2323]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Sep 26 19:08:46 plex systemd[2323]: Reached target Timers.
Sep 26 19:08:46 plex systemd[2323]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Sep 26 19:08:46 plex systemd[2323]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Sep 26 19:08:46 plex systemd[2323]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Sep 26 19:08:46 plex systemd[2323]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Sep 26 19:08:46 plex systemd[2323]: Reached target Sockets.
Sep 26 19:08:46 plex systemd[2323]: Reached target Paths.
Sep 26 19:08:46 plex systemd[2323]: Reached target Basic System.
Sep 26 19:08:46 plex systemd[2323]: Reached target Default.
Sep 26 19:08:46 plex systemd[2323]: Startup finished in 73ms.
Sep 26 19:08:46 plex systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
Sep 26 19:11:15 plex sh[1237]: Connection to 172.104.130.172 closed by remote host.
Sep 26 19:17:01 plex CRON[4641]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep 26 19:18:17 plex systemd[1]: Started Session 4 of user plex.
Sep 26 19:20:26 plex systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Sep 26 19:20:26 plex systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Sep 26 19:34:14 plex sh[1237]: Connection to 176.58.115.42 closed by remote host.
Sep 26 19:39:46 plex systemd[1]: Starting Message of the Day...
Sep 26 19:39:47 plex 50-motd-news[8784]:  * Read about Ubuntu updates for L1 Terminal Fault Vulnerabilities (L1TF).
Sep 26 19:39:47 plex 50-motd-news[8784]:    - https://ubu.one/L1TF
Sep 26 19:39:47 plex 50-motd-news[8784]:  * Having fun with some surprising Linux desktop apps... Alan keeps
Sep 26 19:39:47 plex 50-motd-news[8784]:    the family entertained over the summer/winter holidays.
Sep 26 19:39:47 plex 50-motd-news[8784]:    - https://bict.ly/top_10_entertainment_apps
Sep 26 19:39:47 plex 50-motd-news[8784]:  * Want to make a highly secure kiosk, smart display or touchscreen?
Sep 26 19:39:47 plex 50-motd-news[8784]:    Here's a step-by-step tutorial for a rainy weekend, or a startup.
Sep 26 19:39:47 plex 50-motd-news[8784]:    - https://bitc.ly/secure-kiosk
Sep 26 19:39:47 plex systemd[1]: Started Message of the Day.
```

df -h:

```
plex@plex:~$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               4.4G     0  4.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              899M  1.2M  898M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   49G  7.6G   39G  17% /
tmpfs                              4.4G  8.0K  4.4G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              4.4G     0  4.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                          87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/sda2                          976M  142M  768M  16% /boot
//192.168.178.200/Series            66T   52T   15T  79% /series
//192.168.178.200/Coding            66T   52T   15T  79% /coding
//192.168.178.200/Music             66T   52T   15T  78% /music
//192.168.178.200/Movies            66T   52T   15T  78% /movies
tmpfs                              899M     0  899M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Check `/var/log/syslog` as well as verify disk space isn't used via `df -h`

Comment: According to [VMware's troubleshooting guide for that error message](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2000542), "The error message is seen when a guest operating system running in a VMware virtual machine intentionally halts the virtual CPU by executing the instructions CLI and HLT in succession. This can occur during a critical error or fault within the guest operating system."

Comment: I've added the syslog in the initial post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue affecting VMware ESXi 6.5 and there are three ways to get rid of the issue. I've added vmxnet3.rev.30 = FALSE parameter to the virtual machine.

source: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2151480